# How bad is having two urls returning the same resources?

Tags: rest

Currently in our API it's possible to retrieve all the reviews of a product in two different URLs: '/product/1/reviews' or '/reviews?product=1', could this practice potentially introduce some problems in the future, and if so, what type of problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there is nothing wrong with this, and this is often done. There are some drawbacks though:

If you use HTTP caching, and one of two resources got updated with for example `PUT` or `DELETE` a HTTP client might still retain the old version of the *other* resource.

Generally it is good if you have 2 urls to designate one of the two as the 'true' or canonical url. You can do this with for example a `Link` header (and `rel=canonical`).

You could also have one of the two urls simply redirect to the other (`301 Permanent Redirect`). Any correct HTTP client will follow the redirect.